# Scoping with two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following schema:
[image]

I want to have the option to call `proposals` for both foreign_keys (`author_id` and `editor_id`) as well for separate ones (for example `author_proposals` and `editor_proposals`) and I need to have the option to lazy or eager load them (for example `User.includes(:proposals)` or without it with `joins`).

Update:

```
#I have the scopes which is like this:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :author_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :editor_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :editor_id
end

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :author_id
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :editor_id
end
```

But I need a universal one which it will give me all the proposals (both `author_proposals` and `editor_proposals`) which it will also eager load them. Should I use conditions on `has_many`?

Comment: Post the code that you have written so far for this

Comment: I don't have the code, that is what I am asking! :) What is the preferred way to do it? Is it with scope and passing a lambda? Is it using `conditions`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :editored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :editor_id

  def proposals
    authored_proposals | editored_proposals
  end
end

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :author_id
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :editor_id

  def users
    author | editor
  end
end
```

You can eager load `proposals` by doing: `User.includes(:authored_proposals, :editored_proposals)`. This is not pure rails way, but seems cleaner to me.

---

---

You can also do :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :editored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :editor_id

  has_many : proposals, finder_sql: proc { "SELECT * FROM proposals WHERE (proposals.author_id = #{id} or proposals. editor_id = #{id})" }
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I would do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :editored_proposals, class_name: 'Proposal', foreign_key: :editor_id

  def proposals
    Proposal.where('author_id = :id OR editor_id = :id', { id: id }).distinct
  end
end

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :author_id
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :editor_id

  def users
    User.where(id: [author_id, editor_id].uniq)
  end
end
```

Comment: This one is what I thought at first, I thought to create a new method but I need to eager_load them. So for example this one won't work: 
User.includes(:proposals).first and I don't feel like this is the rails way of doing it.

Comment: Why not just `User.includes(:authored_proposals, :editored_proposals)`?

Comment: Good idea I can add the following:
`scope :proposals, ->(user) { user.includes(:authored_proposals, :editored_proposals) }`
but then when I call `User.proposals` it will always be eage_loaded. I'll be surprised if there isn't any other more rails way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Set your associations like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :author_proposals, :class_name => "Proposal", :foreign_key => "author_id"
  has_many :editor_proposals, :class_name => "Proposal", :foreign_key => "editor_id"
end

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "author_id"
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "editor_id"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is for the simple `author_proposals` and the `editor_proposals` but I need for the proposals which it will find all the proposals.